# Transaction procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

It should make a bank transaction. So i have a table called "transaction" and also an "account" table and a "withdraw" and "deposit". The procedure should create a row in the transaction table. It should call my function which looks if the person is certified. If the user isnt error should show of course. If the transaction has been made the new "saldo" (which is in the account table) of both accounts should be printed. This is what i have so far:

```
create or replace procedure do_transaction(
  p_rownr  in transaction.rownr%type,
  p_pnr    in transaction.pnr%type,
  p_knr    in transaction.knr%type,
  p_date   in transaction."date"%type)
as
not_certified exception;
begin
insert into transaction(rownr,pnr,knr,"date")
values(p_rownr,p_pnr,p_knr,p_date); 
if user <> get_certification(p_pnr,p_knr) then 
raise not_certified; 
end if;
dbms_output.put_line('Pnr: '||''||p_pnr||''||'Current saldo: '||''||get_saldo(p_knr)); /*I also have a function which gets the saldo from the matching knr*/
commit;       
exception  
when not_certified then
raise_application_error(-20007,'Not certified!');
end;
```

The get certification function:

```
create or replace function get_certification( 
p_pnr in bankcust.pnr%type, 
p_knr in account.knr%type) 
return varchar2
as 
v_certification bankcust.pnr%type; 
begin 
select count(*)
into v_certification
from bankcust,account
where pnr = p_pnr 
and knr = p_knr;
return v_certification; 
exception
when no_data_found then
return -1;
end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: your function get_certification will return 0 if nothing found. COUNT(*) does not raise a no data found if no rows, it just returns 0 - I'd say test test and... test

Comment: We do not have your tables or data. So first suggestion is to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to take a guess here as you did not actually state your problem. But that issue is your do_transaction procedure always results in the not certified exception. This is the result of the statement

```
if user <> get_certification(p_pnr,p_knr) then
```

This will **always** evaluate true. It compares the character representation of the result count function from get_certification to the current [user](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/User) (unless the user is presumably '1') thus always resulting in "raise not_certified;" being executed.  Additionally, while not actually an exception but falls into the category of not doing unnecessary work; validate certification before inserting into transaction. So:

```
create or replace procedure do_transaction(
   p_rownr  in transaction.rownr%type,
   p_pnr    in transaction.pnr%type,
   p_knr    in transaction.knr%type,
   p_date   in transaction."date"%type)
as
   not_certified exception;
begin
   if get_certification(p_pnr,p_knr) = 0 then          
      raise not_certified; 
   end if;
  
   insert into transaction(rownr,pnr,knr,"date")
        values(p_rownr,p_pnr,p_knr,p_date); 

   dbms_output.put_line('Pnr: '||''||p_pnr||''||'Current saldo: '||''||get_saldo(p_knr)); /*I also have a function which gets the saldo from the matching knr*/
   commit;       
 exception  
   when not_certified then
     raise_application_error(-20007,'Not certified!');
 end do_transaction;
```